# wwv_flow.g_f01.count not working in apex5 oracle for unchecked rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am running below piece of code on button click but nothing is inserted in dummy_tbl table.

```
   DECLARE
    vRowNumber number;
    BEGIN
     FOR ii IN 1..wwv_flow.g_f01.count LOOP
    vRowNumber := WWV_Flow.g_f01(ii);
      insert into galaxy_apex.dummy_tbl
      values(vRowNumber);
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
    END
```

The call reached to the pl/sql block when I insert some error in it.
wwv_flow.g_f01.count is counting only the rows which are checked. I need to count all rows even if it is unchecked. How to do it?

Comment: Are you able to trace the value of `wwv_flow.g_f01.count`? Are you able to insert simply from outside the loop? Have you tried with `;` after the `END` keyword(for me its missing)?

Comment: furthermore, how are you mapping items to f01? Using `apex.item` or in an ajax call?

Comment: @J.Chomel   how to trace value of wwv_flow.g_f01.count?

Comment: @tom it is check box in tabular form in apex app.

Comment: Well, to trace value of `wwv_flow.g_f01.count`, you either use `dbms_output.put_line(wwv_flow.g_f01.count)` or start your thing in debug mode. If you know not how to do this, you really could improve your productivity by learning how to ***debug***.

Comment: @J.Chomel I got the value for count. but it is counting only checked rows. I want to count all even if it checked or unchecked.

Comment: `g_f01` for a checkbox only gets entries for rows that were checked. If your report has a second editable column, you could use `g_f02` instead as it will have an entry for each row that was posted.

Comment: Also, you probably should be aware that the value of `g_f01(ii)` is merely an index into the other `g_f0x` arrays - so it doesn't make much sense to insert it into a database table.